# Issues with resizing bootstrap-select component

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I decided to use a plugin (http://silviomoreto.github.io/) to beautify the bootstrap select element. This plugins rebuilds the select and its options using a div, a ul and an li for each option.
I have a use case where the options width would be a bit long and I want to set a maximum width for the drop-down that contains them and show a scrollbar whenever required. So far so good.
Although the drop-down menu resizes properly, I am getting a really weird focus box on the long LI itself. Here is a screenshot

[image: Focus box]

This is happening because the LIs sizes are not increased to match the size of the text. I know that because I increases the width using chrome dev-tools.

The LI looks different on different browsers but the issue is the same.

I want to add a css (or a script in the worst case) that can resize the LIs to a proper width to fix this issue but I am not sure how to do that.

Can you please help?

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/sw5j6ppz/

**HTML**

```
<select class="my-select">
<option>Option 1 is way too long for this small select and it will overflow for sure</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").selectpicker({dropupAuto: false});
})
```

**CSS**

```
.my-select div.dropdown-menu {
  width: 200px;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I would like to fix this issue and also keep the scroll-bar so that the select component will look like this:

[image: Desired outcome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS** ( **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wst6ms87/)** )

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  clear:both;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this css:

```
.dropdown-menu span.text{
    white-space:normal;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5qewby7/)**

Comment: I actually like this solution, +1 for that. But I would also like to know if you can do that by forcing scroll-bar on the x direction instead of wrapping the text

Comment: @Alexander what do you mean with **forcing scroll-bar on the x direction**?

Comment: The screen shot above shows scrollbars on the x direction that I would like to keep. Is there a way to solve this issue without wrapping the text? Thanks

Comment: Please @Alexander can you add an image of what do you exactly want?

Comment: I have update the question, please check the new screenshot

Comment: @Alexander I've added a new answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a independent scroll you can try

```
.dropdown-menu li{
   height:35px;
   overflow:scroll 
}
```

(adjust the height what you want)

https://jsfiddle.net/linkita/fj4e2uxs/

Comment: No, I don't want an independent scroll. I want only one at the bottom, please see the screenshot. Thanks for posting.